# Running docker-compose: "Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17"

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose

When trying to run configuration `docker-compose.yml: Compose Deployment`, I get this error

```
#0 62.23 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) o
n project stack-overflow: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
#0 62.23 [ERROR]
#0 62.23 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
#0 62.23 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
#0 62.23 [ERROR]
#0 62.23 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:      
#0 62.23 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I indeed use Java 17. What's wrong about it? I've been using it for a long time, no issues

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
<!-- other props -->
    </properties>
<!-- ... -->
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
```

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T22:49:05+03:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\Семья\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.5.3-bin\2c22a6s60afpuloj4v181qvild\apache-maven-3.5.3 // Maven home is different from project directory and also uses cyrillic letters, as you see. However, it didn't cause any troubles before
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Amazon.com Inc.
Java home: C:\Users\NadChel\.jdks\corretto-17.0.5
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**What should I try to fix it?** My googling ([1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException), [2](https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-error-invalid-target-release-17/)) wasn't fruitful. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410179/fatal-error-compiling-error-invalid-target-release) mentions potential Spring/Tomcat conflicts, but I rely on starters so it should all be figured out by Spring nicely. Besides, I ran [tests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285451/a-test-class-for-a-rest-application) with Docker before, no issues

In case it's relevant, here's my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  stack_overflow_postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: stack_overflow_postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres123
      - POSTGRES_DB=stack_overflow_postgres
    ports:
      - '5411:5432'
  stack_overflow_elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    container_name: stack_overflow_elasticsearch
    restart: always
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=your_password
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'

  stack_overflow_app:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - stack_overflow_postgres
        - stack_overflow_elasticsearch
      environment:
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://stack_overflow_postgres:5432/stack_overflow_postgres
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres123
        - SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_URIS=http://stack_overflow_elasticsearch:9200
        - SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_USERNAME=elastic
        - SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_PASSWORD=your_password
      ports:
        - '8080:8080'
```

**UPD:** khmarbaise said in the comments that I should not define Maven compiler and let Spring do the work. I defined the plugin so that I could define `<annotationProcessorPaths>` for Mapstruct which is used in my project. Mapstruct's [reference guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/pdf/mapstruct-reference-guide.pdf) said it's what I should do (see p. 4). It's also [apparently needed](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) for Lombok support

```xml
<!-- an updated version -->
<version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>
                            -Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=IGNORE
                        </arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
```

Comment: "Apache Maven 3.5.3 (...; 2018-02-24T22:49:05+03:00)" => That is most likely the problem. Use a much more recent Maven version. Or at least ... use a more recent version of the maven compiler plugin.

Comment: The maven version (or the compiler plugin) is not really the problem.. `: invalid target release: 17`. this is the problem... That means you are not using the appropriate JDK version which means JDK17+ based on your compose setup it does not look you are building within the container... or a like....

Comment: If you are already using the spring-boot-starter-parent you should not define the maven-compiler-plugin on your own, because it's already defined by the parent...Apart from that all I strongly recommend to upgrade to most recent version of spring boot (3.1.0) and also upgrade Maven version etc....

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I tried it. See Elliott Frisch's answer and my comment to it

Comment: @khmarbaise can I make it run with Boot 2? Also, I defined the plugin so that I could define `<annotationProcessorPaths>` for Mapstruct

Comment: The problem is JDK17 ... if you need Spring Boot 3.X you need JDK17 ... if you need Spring Boot 2.X you can use JDK17 or less than that...

Comment: @khmarbaise if Spring Boot 2 is compatible with JDK17 ("you can use JDK17"), what's the problem?

Comment: But your environment does not offer that because the configuration `invalid target release: 17` is wrong... maven-compiler-plugin or in Spring Boot `java.version` is wrongly defined...